# Removing Site from Google Search Console

Tags: google-search-console

I have a Search Console set up and added some sites, one of which I no longer want to have in the list shown to me in Search Console.  I have read about 10 site's worth of "just delete it."  But how?!?!?  LOL, I am sure it is obvious, but I cant find it...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

Log in to yur SC-Account and navigate to the Dashboard, there you see all the pages you added. On the left side of each page you see "Manage Property". If you click on this you get a Dropdown with "Delete property"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Took me a while to find this in 2022:

Go to settings. Add the bottom there is a "Remove Property" button which removes the site from Google Search Console.